# Android , Okhttp - how to add subprotocol to websocket connection

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

in my app I'm using OkHttp to establish Websocket connection. Here's method to start connection :

```
private fun start(token: String, id: String, url: String) {
        val request: Request = Request
            .Builder()
            .url(url)
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .header("iD", id)
            .build()
        val listener = ValidationWebSocketListener
        client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
        client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
    }
```

However I have to add subprotocol - "websocket" . How can I achieve that ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't confirmed but it should be possible with

```
request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(...)
                    .addHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "graphql-ws")
...
                    .build();
```